# ¿A qué se debe este error, Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '__del__'"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Este es un ejemplo acerca de como sobre-escribir `__del__`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class P(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print '__del__ work in P'


class C(P):  # class declaration
    def __init__(self): # contructor
        print 'initialized'

    def __del__(self): # destructor
        P.__del__(self) # call parent destructor
        print 'deleted'


c1 = C()
c2 = c1
c3 = c1
print 'all instance refer to the same object:', id(c1) == id(c2) == id(c3)
# del c1
# del c2
# del c3
```

Si lo corro utilizando `del` para `c1`, `c2` y `c3`, se eliminan las referencias a estas instancias y funciona de acuerdo a lo esperado.

Pero si comento las 3 últimas lineas, obtengo este error que no entiendo:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '__del__'" in <bound method C.__del__ of <__main__.C object at 0x1007b1fd0>> ignored
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? y ¿Por qué al final dice *ignored*?

Answer (score 3):

En la respuesta de kikocorreoso está el por qué el método `__del__` falla. Eso responde parcialmente a la pregunta.

El error de la pregunta ocurre porque: `P` ya no existe cuando se intenta `P.__del__`. Al no existir `P` lo único que existe es algo de tipo `NoneType` (`None`) y ese tipo no dispone de método `__del__`. De ahí la excepción de tipo `AttributeError`

Ocurre porque no existen referencias a la clase `P` que mantengan la clase viva. Y aunque las hubiera pueden ser borradas en primer lugar. Dado que el ciclo de borrado de referencias durante el borrado del módulo no está para ser controlado, lo que se puede hacer es capturar la excepción:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; py-indent-offset:4 -*-
###############################################################################
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)


class P(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print('__del__ work in P')


class C(P):  # class declaration
    def __init__(self):  # contructor
        print('initialized')

    def __del__(self):  # destructor
        try:
            P.__del__(self)  # call parent destructor
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            print('deleted')

c1 = C()
c2 = c1
c3 = c1
print('all instance refer to the same object:', id(c1) == id(c2) == id(c3))
# del c1
# del c2
# del c3
```

Así no se producen errores porque se captura la excepción.  Se podría hilar más fino y hacer un `getattr` sobre `P` del método `__del__` para asegurar que la excepción `AttributeError` realmente es por eso y no ocurre dentro del método `P.__del__` (porque `P.__del__` podría generar la excepción que se propagaría y sería capturada por el bloque `try` / `except` / `else` en `C.__del__`)

Answer (score 1):

¿La excepción ocurre de forma un poco aleatoria?

En la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) puedes leer los siguientes extractos:

> **Note:** `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for `x` by one, and the latter is only called when `x`‘s reference count reaches zero. Some common situations that may prevent the reference count of an object from going to zero include: circular references between objects (e.g., a doubly-linked list or a tree data structure with parent and child pointers); a reference to the object on the stack frame of a function that caught an exception (the traceback stored in `sys.exc_info()` keeps the stack frame alive); or a reference to the object on the stack frame that raised an unhandled exception in interactive mode (the traceback stored in `sys.last_traceback` keeps the stack frame alive). The first situation can only be remedied by explicitly breaking the cycles; the second can be resolved by freeing the reference to the traceback object when it is no longer useful, and the third can be resolved by storing None in `sys.last_traceback`. Circular references which are garbage are detected and cleaned up when the cyclic garbage collector is enabled (it’s on by default). Refer to the documentation for the [`gc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#module-gc) module for more information about this topic.

Mira lo que está en negrita y cursiva en el siguiente extracto:

> **Warning:** Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, ***exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored***, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down). For this reason, `__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

En general, `__del__` no se debería usar ya que el recolector de basura se encarga de ir eliminando lo que no es necesario. Si se decide usar `__del__` debería usarse para que haga lo mínimo.

Respecto a porqué sale el error/*warning*, cuando heredas de `P` ya estás heredando su método `__del__`, ¿por qué sobreescribirlo? Solo tiene sentido si, además, quieres que el método haga alguna cosa extra. Por otra parte, el método `__del__` de la clase `P`, usado tal como lo usas, solo acepta instancias de la clase `P` pero `self` ahí es una instancia de la clase `C`. De ahí el error/*warning*. Y como ocurre dentro del método `__del__` es ignorado.